# Installed updates, now unity / compiz wont load

Tags: unity, 13.10, compiz

I just allowed Ubuntu (13.10) to update after being away from work since December.  Now when I boot I get the normal login screen (everything looks fine here) but as soon as I log in I have no window borders, no sidebar or task bar.  Whenever I try to restart unity or compiz I see this

```
craigb@mybox:~$ unity
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: core
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: core
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: ccp
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: ccp
compizconfig - Info: Backend     : gsettings
compizconfig - Info: Integration : true
compizconfig - Info: Profile     : unity
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: composite
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: composite
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: opengl
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: opengl
LLVM ERROR: Program used external function '__morestack' which could not be resolved!
```

willing to run extra diagnostics, just tell me what to type hehe.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same issue.  Eventually I ended up here (https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xserver-xorg-video-intel/+bug/1188123)

and noticed that issue arose with the xserver-xorg-intel-video package, so I did:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall xserver-xorg-video-intel
```

Which fixed it for me (after purging the nvidia drivers I already had, which did not fix the issue).  Someone who knows more can hopefully contribute as well.  Good luck.